# How can one make an associative array with objects as values in processing?

Tags: processing

I have tried using the Hashmap data structure to create an associative array in processing with objects as values and, of course, strings as keys.

http://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html

However, I couldn't get the values of my hash map to be objects of a class I made.

Here is what I tried:

```java
class Person {

    public String firstName, lastName;

    Person(String f, String l) {
        this.firstName = f;
        this.lastName = l;
    }

}

HashMap<Person> persons;
persons = new HashMap();
```

Processing returns a bizarre error:

```java
Cannot find anything named "persons"
```

Comment: Did you cast them to those objects? Where is your sniplet? Would be nice to see.

Comment: What's your base language? C#, Java or what? Can you put your code here so it will make it easy to understand problem.

Comment: I'm using the language of processing, which is based off of Java. I will be able to get a code snippet up asap.

Comment: try `HashMap<Person> persons = new HashMap()<Person>`; and then access by persons.get("index here");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic HashMap:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// Save data:
map.put("associativeIndex", new Object());

// Access data:
map.get("associativeIndex");
```